# Build Action for large set of images?

Tags: .net, image, build, gdi+, buildaction

I'm in Visual Studio 2008 and I have a project that loads lots of images.  I want the images to be deployed to the local instance of the software running.  The trouble is that I tried using the images as a resource, but there are apparently too many(200 to 300) because I get strange build errors like GDI+ exceptions and Out of Memory Exceptions.  This got me to thinking:  "Maybe I'm going about it wrong?"  What should I be doing for my large set of images?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply add a new folder to my project, add existing items to the folder, and then highlight the images and set the build action to compile.  This seems to work in Debug mode.  I haven't actually tried to release the project yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a post-build step to copy them to a known location in the output folder (ie $(target_dir)\images) then let the program load them from disk.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too.  Actually, though, I solved the problem.  I'll post the answer here in a sec.